# How do you use load data from a CSV in C++ TensorFlow?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to load a model trained in Python into C++ and classify some data from a CSV. I found this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@hamedmp/exporting-trained-tensorflow-models-to-c-the-right-way-cf24b609d183#.3bmbyvby0

Which lead me to this piece of example code:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc

Which is looking very hopeful for me. However, the data I want to load is in a CSV, and not an image file, so I'm trying to rewrite the ReadTensorFromImageFile function. I was able to find a class DecodeCSV, but it's  a little different than the DecodePNG and DecodeJpeg classes in the example code, and I end up with an OutputList instead of and Output. Using the [] operator on the list seems to crash my program. If anyone happens to know how to deal with this, it would be greatly appreciated. He are the relevant changes to the code:

```
// inside ReadTensorFromText
Output image_reader;
    std::initializer_list<Input>* x = new std::initializer_list<Input>;
    ::tensorflow::ops::InputList defaults = ::tensorflow::ops::InputList(*x);
    OutputList image_read_list;
    image_read_list = DecodeCSV(root.WithOpName("csv_reader"), file_reader, defaults).output;
    // Now cast the image data to float so we can do normal math on it.
    // image_read_list.at(0) crashes the executable.
    auto float_caster =
        Cast(root.WithOpName("float_caster"), image_read_list.at(0), tensorflow::DT_FLOAT);
```

Comment: hey were you able to achieve this ? I want to do something similar

Comment: I couldn't find a built in function in the Tensorflow C++ library, but I was able to parse the CSV in regular C++ and classify it, it just took a little bit of work to get the data into a tensor object.

Comment: thanks, i ended up doing the same

Comment: @IanConway - could you promote your comment to an answer so others know you found a good solution (and you get credit)? :)  Thanks!